# Marketing Bonus

Tags: communication, salary, bonus

I'm moving into marketing from IT, and we're reevaluating my wages.  I'm an hourly worker, and I want to propose a salary + bonus structure.  However, it seems that any bonus structures I find when Googling are sales-oriented.  Is there any rhyme or reason to this?  Is it because it's easier to quantify a sales target?

Does anyone have any suggestions on doing a bonus?  I'm thinking a certain percentage above and beyond our projected growth of monthly revenue.

And do employers prefer a yearly bonus to a quarterly one?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Agree some Key Performance Indicators (KPIs) which you can directly influence in your work and which the company agrees are factors influencing profitability. They should be numeric and unambiguous. Set a bonus structure based on those.

KPIs for your specific role are better than overall company performance because there are a lot of other things influencing overall performance on which your personal output has no bearing.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Depends on the KPIs! :)

Answer (score 1):

As keshlam mentioned, it is easier to assign bonuses where the benefit to the company is measurable. You'll need to look at how to assign profitability to activities the marketing team carries out.

This is a reasonably well understood area, so you should be able to find information on kpi's easily, but an example would be sales increases after marketing initiatives.

Many companies arrange bonuses to encompass company profitability, department profitability, and even individual performance against objectives or targets.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, you should define clear KPIs. I believe you want a bonus strictly dependant on your performance, so here are some examples (not in any particular order).

- Brand awareness. There are various metrics, the simplest being the number of unique visitors and the number of Google searches. Find one and quantify a relation between *+x* visits and *+y* bonus.
- Monetization and engagement metrics. From "knowing the brand" to "buying the product on a regular basis", you have a number of steps. Improving any part of the process will improve the final sales. 
  To make this more concrete, here is an example, please bear with me on this one. Take 100 people. Ask them *"Do you know the brand Apple ?"* - 95 will answer yes. Ask these *"Do you consider Apple products to be good ?"* - 76 will answer yes, i.e. 80% of the people who know the brand consider their products good. Ask these *"Would you consider buying an Apple product?"*. 38 will answer yes, i.e. 50% of the people who consider the products to be good. Ask these *"have you already bought a product?*, 25 will answer yes, i.e. ~65% of the people who consider buying. Ask these *"do you regularly buy at Apple ?"*, 10 will answer yes, i.e. 40%. 
  Improve any of these percentages, and you have improved your final sales - which is the job of Marketing.
- Social Media impact. You can use Facebook Analytics, Google Analytics, etc. to see the reach of your posts. You can also calculate the correlation between your page's followers and your latest productions.
- Cost of production against number of targets reached. If you manage to produce your marketing content for half the price and reach the same amount of people, you effectively saved money for the company. Conversely, if with the same price, you reach twice the amount of people, you improved the efficiency of your advertising.
- Build your own product survey. Identify the method and the target population as clearly as possible with your boss. Make your bonus contingent to the answers of the survey. You need to make this as objective as possible, so that you cannot be ever accused of twisting the results or the respondants to get favorable results, so this will have to be a long discussion with your boss.

For the question about Quarterly vs Yearly bonus, it depends where you live. Here in France, I have never heard of quarterly bonuses.

Answer (score 1):

Some companies simply offer everyone outside sales a profit-sharing bonus in years when the company is doing well, based on some fraction of salary scaled by that employee's annual performance rating. It isn't a commission, and it's usually a much smaller part of the total salary, but it's supposed to serve a similar purpose of encouraging folks to overachieve.

Note that sales base salaries are often artificially lowered so salesmen have to meet reasonable goals just to get their   intended salary. The potential bonus for overachieving is higher, but there is a de facto cash penalty for underachieving. Think log and hard before suggesting that other adopt the commission system; are you really willing to be paid less than you are now if a marketing campaign doesn't do as well as expected?

Also, there is some fairly strong research that after a point where the employee's needs are met, money isn't as strong a motivator as it might seem. I certainly seek a raise more as a concrete "ya done good" signal than as income per se, and I'm not that highly paid for my industry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as far as I can tell it's because salesmen's productivity is directly measured in income produced for the company and hence is easy to reward on a commission basis. Few, if any, other positions are that simple.